# In my pronouns god me defend

Tags: pronunciation, archaicisms, scottish-english, motto

The motto of the UK monarch is apparently not the same in all parts of the kingdom: In Scotland, it [is](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In_My_Defens_God_Me_Defend):

> In My Defens God Me Defend

Ok, but - how do I pronounce this? Is "defens" pronounced like modern-English "defense"? Is the 'e' in "me" like in "beer", or like in "test"? What about the 'e's in "Defend"?

Comment: It's an old spelling, but it's the same word as *defense*. And I don't think there's any need to pronounce it the way it would have been pronounced in Scotland in 1488.